# postgres SQL state: P0001 error in when running function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, function

*Postgres DB*

If I run below function using query **SELECT sms.somefunc();**, got error **SQL state: P0001**.

I called another function within this function.

Can someone help me to sort out this issue? I don't know why this error occur.

Thanks in advance.

```
--DROP FUNCTION SMS.somefunc();

CREATE FUNCTION SMS.somefunc() RETURNS void AS $BODY$

DECLARE

    wk_rows INT :=0;
    work_plan_id_val INT :=0;
    DECLARE wp_rows     INT DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN

    DECLARE wk_plan_id CURSOR FOR 

        SELECT COUNT(work_plan_id) FROM sms.work_plan 
            WHERE class_general_id = 8 AND
            subject_general_id = 18;

        BEGIN
            OPEN wk_plan_id;
                FETCH wk_plan_id INTO wk_rows;
            CLOSE wk_plan_id;
        END;

    DECLARE wp CURSOR FOR 

        SELECT work_plan_id FROM sms.work_plan 
            WHERE class_general_id = 8 AND
            subject_general_id = 18;  --442

        BEGIN
            OPEN wp;
            IF wk_rows > 0 THEN
                wp_rows = 0;
                WHILE wp_rows < wk_rows LOOP
                    FETCH wp INTO work_plan_id_val;

                    RAISE NOTICE 'work_plan_id_val %', work_plan_id_val;
                    EXECUTE SMS.P_DELETE_X (work_plan_id_val,'admin');
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Something happen %', work_plan_id_val;

                    wp_rows = wp_rows + 1;
                    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST');
                END LOOP;
            END IF;
            CLOSE wp;
        END;

END;

$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION SMS.somefunc()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you would to use statement `PERFORM` not `EXECUTE`.

```
EXECUTE SMS.P_DELETE_X (work_plan_id_val,'admin');
```

should be

```
PERFORM SMS.P_DELETE_X (work_plan_id_val,'admin');
```

The `EXECUTE` statement should be used for dynamic SQL, not for function execution.

There is another smaller issue - you should to use `EXISTS` instead `count(*)` - and another issue - it is classic example of slow ISAM style.